# Blender 2.8 - CTRL+R not working(loop cut and slide tool)

Tags: loop

Pressing CTRL+R on the attached file does not activate the loop and cut tool.
Why is this tool not working in this context?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model is just one big N-GON, and the tool only works on quads. [Check out this link](https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-modeling/training/modeling/tris-quads-n-gons/) to learn a little more about modeling with tris, quads and n-gons.

[image: Better topology]

This is your model (remade by me) with much better topology.  The loop cut and slide tool will work correctly with this kind of topology.  Also, getting your model to look like this will give you some good modeling practice.